# Blender export to Unity

Tags: texturing, export, unity, .fbx

I tried to export blender assets to Unity.
I know it's a common thread in this Stack.
But I still didn't figured it out.

Blender crash like half a time whenever I try to bake.

I figure out how to get the baked images, and save it in a texture folder.

But the FBX export doesn't have the required material in UNITY and show only in with grey mat. 
Whenever I try to make my own material with the baked image and apply to the models, it doesn't fit to the models, it is not following its UVs.

Is there a "easy" way to export to fbx including its materials. 
I tried [FBX addon bundle exporter](https://bitbucket.org/renderhjs/blender-addon-fbx-bundle) but it did not work. 
(Missing files I guessed ?)

I'm using the Cycle render with the PBR Materials Add on Blender 2.79.

Comment: Please add your blender version and rendering engine (cycles/br/eevee) you are creating your materials in. In general UV maps transfer using Unity's importer for fbx and blend, but you may have to manually reassign the textures to the materials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exporting from Cycles to FBX is somewhat fiddly at the moment still. 
As far as i'm aware the exporter reads only trough a principled node - and then not all slots.
I found this Method to somewhat work, its essentially the same as it has been with the old Blender render:

**1.** For the images to be packed into the .fbx there are two important parts, first you need to connect them to certein inputs of a principled bsdf node. Sadly not all work tough (at least for me atm) i expected the normal input to also work, but it didn't.
 [image]

**2.** When exporting to .fbx theres two settings you need to change:

[image] [image]

You need to change "Path Mode" to "Copy" and hit the small icon behind it, i'm currently on 2.8 but the method should apply to 2.79

After that, you can try to reimport the texture into Blender, your Textures should show up in the image/UV Editor.