# How do I export an fbx with textures?

Tags: texturing, export

I want to export an FBX with textures. How do I do it? All I get is the model without textures. Please explain with as much detail as possible. Basically I want to convert an GLB into FBX with textures because Unity doesn't like GLB.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132246/blender-export-to-unity