# Applying Logo to Sphere to move to Unity

Tags: uv, image, unity

Ok, so I'm really stuck here and need some help everybody. I'm trying to color an icosphere yellow, then apply a red target (transparent png) to 6 sides of the ball (left, right, front, back, top, bottom) in Blender 2.9.

Using an icosphere from Blender, it's already unwrapped, but holy crap I cannot figure this out for the life of me. I've tried importing the image as a plane, shrinkwrapping and baking that with the texture. I've tried unwrapping just a section of the ball and apply something to it. I tried using nodes in materials to connect the image texture, I tried opening an image in the UV editor and positioning it there.

I either get a) nothing at all or b) a very dark, muddy image of everything combined when baking the texture. Neither shows up in Unity at all.  I dont need to attach the Blend file because it was just a ball, but I have attached the image I'm trying to use. If anybody can get me a little closer I would be super appreciative.

Thanks.

[image]

P.S. - This is my best attempt using a MixRGB shader and then dropping the whole Blend file into my Unity project folder:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- in *Edit* mode select all vertices and *Unwrap* as **Cube Projection**
- go to *UV Editor* and *Scale* the UV a bit up
- go to *Shader Editor* and for *Image* node - change *Repeat* to **Clip**

[image]

Note: in this case I didn't use *Texture Coordinates* node since UV is used by default and *Mapping* node since positioning is controlled by *UV Map*

### Unity

Im not experienced with Unity, so there is probably better way, but looks like

- in Blender - Bake material into textures (Color (Albedo), Metalic, Normal, Ambient,  ... etc for PBR material)
- export as FBX
- in Unity import asset and assign baked texture to Albedo channel

[image]

Check documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html
Also search Blender to Unity topic like here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/132340/2214

Comment: Thanks so much! this worked perfectly! (Not sure how to put a screenshot in a comment but looks just like yours).

Dragging the Blend file into Unity just gives me the gray mesh still, so I'll have to figure out how to export this material/textures into something I can rebuild in Unity I think.

Comment: Well, for not being experienced with Unity you're doing better than me at the moment lol. I'm getting a lot closer though. Following exactly what you did I'm able to get both my model and it's baked textures into Unity, I set up a new material and slapped it on a FBX of the object. However, it seems extremely dark when I bake the diffuse channel for color (no albedo available). Can I ask how you baked a perfectly lit texture like that?

Comment: Under Bake Properties switch Bake Type to Diffuse and under Influence disable Direct and Indirect (keep only Color). Or if you need just a Color texture (like here) you can simply connect Mix node directly to Material output. I'm not sure if Color Management influents result, if so switch from Filmic to Standard. Tip for baking multiple passes on one click there if an addon Bake Tool ($) that can helps.

Comment: This did the trick! (in filmic). Finally pinpointing a better process for an upcoming project.  Many thanks again!