# Add face image decal (which made also in Blender as a object)

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

The issue maybe simple but im cracking my head for half a day already trying different methods.

What I need: I made this little cute cloud and want to add face to it

[image]

Buut.. this face is also made as object

[image]

I have a vertices restriction and want to keep it 500 (the cloud body is 500 now). So if i add this face as object - i have additional 462 vertices, which i dont need. If i screenshot face impression and cut out the extra parts to make transparent image - there is noise at the edges, which i cant remove. (image restriction is also 256x256 px)

If i ignore the blurred edges and add as Alpha image just the face impression - get all faces behind transparent..
[image]

How are you guys doing this, any simple way to make this happen?

Edit:
Also tried with mix RGB nodes, but I have a gradient as a base color
[image]

Blend file
[image]

Comment: Why dont use face expression image directly as texture of your cloud? Why do you need image decal in this case?

Comment: i have one, but is low quality and have lots of noise.. i also want base color as a gradient. Im thinking to screenshot a better quality face expression with a gradient plane mesh behind and make it as texture.. Just wondering what is a proper way to make it

Comment: I understood you use two objects (cloud and face shrinked to cloud). I suggested to use only cloud with face texture in mterial like here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/195024/2214 or here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249069/2214 or here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201198/2214

Comment: Thx. means i still need to create the texture (the face expression with body gradient) in photoshop like app? Coz it was more easier for me to create face in blender

Comment: Have you tried the Shrinkwrap modifier?

Comment: @Blender_noob Please share your file you deal with via https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Wow, so easy thing took me 1 whole day.. Tried through photoshop, but realized that I cant draw there perfectly, so given up the idea.. Tried baking texture and add image to it, but due to 256x256 restriction - its pixelated. Jaco - nope, did not.
@vklidu - uploading now
I think all issues is due to low poly/low resolution restriction. Guess I will just give up the idea of other items I wanted to add in and make the good quality face expression as a cut project.

Comment: then render just the face with alpha or on a white background, and use the render as a texture... also looks like you carefully modeled it as a mesh, you can try to use 3 solid color materials to render the face if the texture looks pixelated

Comment: @calambre - thx.. I thought of it, but is there a way to render just plain colors image without setting out the studio lights? Coz when I try it with lights, the colors are not same, need good experience with lights.. 
I tried with low quality transparent face that I have, can be done, the only issue is that behind the image with alpha I can't get gradient color (solid ok). I not sure how to configure nodes to make color behind to be gradient. I used MIX RGB->Diffuse BSDF. If I plug gradient to color-1, I get the whole palette appear at alpha places

Comment: you can use Emission instead of Principled to render the texture, which is like shadeless, connect your texture or use colored 3 materials... in this last case you need to move part of your geometry cause they lay in the same plane... here's a [quick render](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bcajlc51ateyarr/cloud%2000.jpg?dl=1)

Comment: Holy moly.. That is what i was also looking for.. Now looking how to do it
Mind to share what settings to use pls (I mean in render or node).. Oh, ok, think I got it, just render with Evee, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few notes ...

- it is better to create face from 2D curves for smooth silhouethes
  (you can Convert to Curve, switch Curve Spline type to Bezier, Handles > Automatic for most of control points, just for corners set type Vector ... for sure the best build from scratch :) )
- Render face by Camera > Orthographic as close as possible to fill 256x256 px texture ... Set Film > Transparent
- Completely shadeless material than can look like this ...

[image]

Comment: Thx for advice, i will go back and retry once more with the curves..

Comment: Another thing is - after I render the face as 256x256, I give it the whole space in the UV map, gradient color I gave about 20x20px. In the end the face resolution come out acceptable to view. I did not know about UV resolution allocation, just happened to see on YT yesterday. Thx a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Thx Everyone for your inputs. Really great suggestions and get my answers.
First of all - all my issues are came from low restrictions on mesh as well as the texture image, if you don't have this, then should not face this issue.

None the less, below how I solve it:

1. Thx to **@vklidu** and this link - [How do I adjust an image on a sphere?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201167/how-do-i-adjust-an-image-on-a-sphere/201198#201198) I played around with the nodes and solve Transparent image + gradient background with a **mapping node** + **plane mesh** as mapped object (using its coordinates I mapped and zoomed the correct color gradient to my object).. Maybe its not the correct way to do, but it's working.

[image]

2. Thx to **@calambre** for advise on how to render plain image from viewport without setting up all the lights, environment, reflections, etc - I was not able to find this method online, but is really good to render plain high quality images from your objects.

This is how it setup for render (Emission strength should be 2). Use Evee:

[image]

3. Now the final setup - I can easily edit this rendered image and place it in the Step-1. It rendered really good quality for me
   [image]