# How do I import an fbx file into unity with the texture included

Tags: .fbx

I have a file in blender and want to insert it into unity. I have managed to export it as an FBX and put in into Unity but when I do, the object is completely white. Please keep in mind I have zero experience with blender and have to use version 2.7 only.

Comment: Getting unity to play nice with blender exports is a common problem people have, make sure next time to check if other people have already asked and have gotten answers for your problem. You can find a good answer here -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/132340/61453

Comment: Depending on how you exported it, [this post](https://www.cgtrader.com/tutorials/1542-importing-an-fbx-file-into-unity-with-textures) might help. If you didn't export your Textures, you should be able to save them from the UV Editing or Texture Paint Tab.